# What rules and regulation do I need to keep in mind when purchasing property in India while on H1B

Tags: india, real-estate, property-taxes

I am currently in the US on an H1B visa. I want to buy a flat in India for my parents. But I am not aware of any rules and regulations regarding taxes or any restrictions if there are any. I will be taking a home loan. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction on where I should begin and what I need to be aware of and consider while making decisions. I can google the intricacies of the procedures based on your answers but I am looking for guidance on how to begin since I am completely new to this and worried about falling prey to scams.

(Although I want the flat to be in my parents' names, I want to keep it a surprise all the way until the end when everything is finalized - so I cannot ask my parents for help)

Thank you!